# Getting Error while calling SOAP API from Postman: Invalid Content-Type:application/xml. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, postman

I am learning SOAP API with Springboot. I have created basic flow according to tutorial but when I am getting error when I am calling ENDPOINT from the postman.

I tried to find out solution by adding content-type="application/xml" but I am still getting error like

> com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/xml. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

I am not able to figure out what is the issue.
If I am sending request in wrong format or I made wrong configuration for SOAP.

**school.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="student"
       targetNamespace="student" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="StudentDetailsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="StudentDetailsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Student">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="standard" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Config.java**

```
package com.soap.wsdl.config;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class Config extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext 
applicationContext)
{
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/api/*");
}

@Bean(name = "studentDetailsWsdl")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema)
{
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("StudentDetailsPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/api/");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("student");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema countriesSchema()
{
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("school.xsd"));
}
}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package com.soap.wsdl.controller;

import com.soap.wsdl.dto.StudentDetailsRequest;
import com.soap.wsdl.dto.StudentDetailsResponse;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

@Endpoint
public class StudentController {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "student";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "StudentDetailsRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public void getCountry(@RequestPayload StudentDetailsRequest request) {
       StudentDetailsResponse response = new StudentDetailsResponse();
       System.out.println(request);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.8</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.soap</groupId>
<artifactId>soap</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo-soap</name>
<description>Springboot with SOAP API</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image: POSTMAN API call]

Answer (score 1):

SOAP UI sends Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks @Wladimir. It is resolved now.
Can you also explain concept behind NAMESPACE_URI in Controller, TargetNamespace in Config, targetNameSpace in xsd file and xmlns:gs.
It was not working until I make changes and set "http://www.howtodoinjava.com/xml/school". Not getting this concept.